# How to run local host on Iphone using swift ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift

I have a local ruby on rails server set up on -

http://localhost:3000/

I have added allow arbitrary loads in the info.plist

When I run the app on the simulator it works fine, but when I try to run it on the iPhone it doesn't. The app just crashes.

Looking at similar questions I found that I need to use the actual IP. I also turned the Internet sharing on from the preferences.

So I found out my local IP address which is - 192.168.0.8

So in Safari I am testing it out like this http://192.168.0.8:3000/

But it doesn't work!

How can I get this up and running?

Comment: First, I assume the "local IP address" of 192.168.0.8 is for the computer upon which you are running Ruby on Rails? Second, is your iPhone on your wifi network when you try that URL? Or is it on cellular? That 192.168.x.x address will only be accessible if both computers are on the same local network, not if the phone is connecting via cellular.

Comment: BTW, simply saying "it doesn't work" isn't very informative. So, if it crashed, you have to tell us what the error was. You likely are force unwrapping some optional that is `nil`. If that's the case, don't use `!` to unwrap optional, but do `guard let` or `if let` to safely unwrap the optionals. And, if the request failed, you should let us know what the `error` object was. And if `response` and `data were not `nil`, what did they contain?

Comment: Yes as Rob said, you can only accessto 192.168 if both your sever and your iphone are on the same internet. Can you please confirm that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your rails server like this:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

Note that if you have a firewall on your computer you may need to open your firewall or run on another port, like port 80.

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier if you [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Just start your server, as usually and by default with port 3000, and then run ngrok as to start listening on such port:

```
./ngrok http 3000
```

This will give you a public IP which will be accessible for your devices.